# Meterial Design javascript method from Angular 7 component

Tags: javascript, angular

***Solved it by using: 'declare var md:any;' after imports ***

I am building a website in which I am using 'creative tim template for dashboard' 
I am using date and time picker, the issue I am facing is the DateTime picker is initialized only once and **'it worked when the component and loaded for the first time but when I switch components then DateTime picker stop working'**,

the solution that I've found out is I have to initialize DateTime picker every time component is loaded by using the initialize method in the component 
but then I receive the error **src/app/components/booktrip/booktrip.component.ts(24,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'md'.**

here's my code

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Trip } from '../../mockups/trip.mockup';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-book-trip',
   templateUrl: './book-trip.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./book-trip.component.css']
 })
 export class BookTripComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
   ngOnInit() {
     md.initFormExtendedDatetimepickers();
   }
   bookTrip(trip) {
     console.log(trip);
   }
}
```

My angular.json is

```
 "scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/core/jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/core/popper.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/moment.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/sweetalert2.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/jquery.bootstrap-wizard.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-selectpicker.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/jasny-bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/fullcalendar.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/jquery-jvectormap.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/nouislider.min.js",
          "src/assets/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/arrive.min.js",
          "src/assets/buttons.github.io/buttons.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/chartist.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js",
          "src/assets/js/material-dashboard.min40a0.js",
          "src/assets/demo/demo.js",
          "src/assets/demo/jquery.sharrre.js"
        ]
```

and the error i am getting is 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY1wB.png)

I am not able to generate production build.

**I am stuck for too long.. is there any possible solution ??**

Comment: Can you show were you defined `md`?

Comment: it is in the 'src/assets/js/material-dashboard.min40a0.js'

Comment: Can you show the complete code of your component?

Comment: here You go @Max

Comment: What is md here?

Comment: I can't see a definition or import of md, that might be the reason of your error. I just wunder who it was working before.

Comment: md is defined in the javascript plugin i  have used for datetime picker ,if i dont use this method  "md.initFormExtendedDatetimepickers();" the datetime picker doesnot work if we switch components using routerLink

Comment: where do you import that plugin?

Comment: Your error reminds me to some errors I had when using the moment.js, therefore my solutions was to import moment from moment.js in every component where is used it.

Comment: @Max but it works cause when the scripts .js is generated . it finds the md when build is generated ..

Comment: @Max yeah that will be the last solution but there must be anyway to use plugins functions in component without importing each plugin on every component other wise there is no sense to include scripts in angular

Comment: I think you could import md in `main.ts` to avoid that. But somewhere you have to import it. Outher whise the compiler don't now wher to search for md

Comment: And it works, because as you told, md is defined in your `material-dashboard.min40a0.js`, but the compiler doesn't now that, but when the browser executed your compiled js it will find md in in your plugin.

Comment: solved it by using 'declare var md:any;' after imports ..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only a TypeScript error, and that md is actually defined -it's just that TypeScript doesn't know about it-.

Have you tried importing it directly to the files where you use md?

```
import * as md from 'material-dashboard';
```

You can read more about it here: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af

This is how I think your component should look like, in the end:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Trip } from '../../mockups/trip.mockup';

import * as md from 'material-dashboard';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-book-trip',
   templateUrl: './book-trip.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./book-trip.component.css']
 })
 export class BookTripComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
   ngOnInit() {
     md.initFormExtendedDatetimepickers();
   }
   bookTrip(trip) {
     console.log(trip);
   }
}
```

Comment: After the imports in the BookTripComponent file? And did you keep the import * as md from 'material-dashboard';?

Comment: no the error was only appearing in terminal not in browser 

btw solved this just by adding "declare var md:any;"